# How can I restore a disappeared battery tray icon indicator?

Tags: indicator, battery, system-tray

My battery tray icon indicator suddenly disappeared:

[image]

I didn't install or remove any software.

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reinstalling *indicator-power*

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-power
```

Other possiblity is that it is disabled in the gnome registry

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Then use `dconf-editor` to change icon-policy to present.